# Simple beginning Tutorial for Spring-Data-Rest

Tags: spring-data-rest

Hi I would like to learn spring data rest, but It is very confused. Which dependencies I have to add to the pom, as the default (spring-data-rest) How I structure the xml files or the configuration classes. It' s very heavy. 
How I create an connection to database, and so on.

Comment: You're asking really broad question... Would You like to try reading some material first and coming up with specific narrower ones?

Comment: Yes, I reading the the documentation and the sample project sources from spring.io website. It always describe, the ways to build an spring-data-projekt with starter-boot. The other ways, like an normal webapplication failed. The documentation always contains the configuration with java classes and non xml files.

Answer (score 0):

SDR documentation needs to be improved and I am sure Spring team are working on that. Having said that the best way to understand most of the SDR is through API docs. Also team lead is maintaining a [Restbucks sample app](https://github.com/olivergierke/spring-restbucks) that helps you understand/use various features of SDR